# How do you declare a manifest.json link tag on a restricted site governed by Apache shibboleth?

Tags: javascript, json, progressive-web-apps

The console showing error when trying to reach the `manifest.json`, I have it declared as:

```
<link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
```

can the manifest tag be declared inline, or what would be the best way to declare it in this case?

`<link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>` is unreachable unless already logged in the browser.

```
<link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
```

These is the error message showing on console:

> Access to fetch at
>   'manifest.json' redirected from 'https://example.com' from origin
>   'https://restrictedexample.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if someone else will need help with something similar but, using the following tag solved my problem:

```
<link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials"/>
```

Now, I am not receiving any errors anymore.